# write to register, read back and compare not working

Tags: c, cpu-registers, i2c

I'm writing a section of C code where I write some values into a register (from an i2c device), read back the value from the register and compare if the value is the same. It looks like this:

```
typedef struct
{
   uint8      address;  //address of the i2c slave register
   uint8      value;    // value which have to be written into the register
} messages;


messages *pMsg;

void write_to_i2c( uint8 address, uint8 value)
{
   i2c_Instance()->DTR  = address;     //DTR is the Data Transmit Register     of i2c
   i2c_Instance()->DTR  = value;
}

uint8 read_from_i2c( uint8 address )
{
   i2c_Instance()->DTR  =  address;
   return  i2c_Instance()->DTR);
}


write_to_i2c( pMsg->address, pMsg->value )

tempReadback = read_from_i2c( pMsg->address); //write the read value into a variable

if (tempReadback == pMsg->value) //compare if the written value is the same as the read value
{
   return OK;
}

else
{
   return NOT_OK
}
```

So far, OK. The function void write_to_i2c writes the message to the i2c register.The message is the register address of the i2c slave device and the value which have to be written into the register.

The function "read_from_i2c" just reads back the value which are written into the register of the i2c slave device. When I debug the code I can see the correct values into the registers but I end every time within the else loop. So, the question is: Is the way I compare the values the correct one?

Comment: What's the difference between `i2c_HwInstance` and `i2c_Instance`? Because read function uses the later, whereas write function use the other one.

Comment: I assume you should throw in the occasional `volatile`  to indicate to the compiler that you want it to read the memory at the given address, and that you want it to write through when you write (or it may optimize away the write because it apparently has "no effect", and not read again because it can prove that the value hasn't changed).

Comment: Does you user manual specify that the value read will be the same as the value written?   Often, there are two peripheral registers specified at the same address, one for reading, one for writing, or the address may be read-only or write-only and undefined for the other operation.  Worse, the manual could say 'NOTE: THIS ADDRESS MUST NEVER BE WRITTEN TO', or the like.

Comment: @Aif sorry, it was a mistake. It's only i2c_Instance